# Subquery in SQL Server Compact Edition : Update Table from an other Table

Tags: sql-server, subquery, sql-server-ce

I want to update a table from another table with SQL Server CE database:

```
 UPDATE [ConfigurationInterCaisse] 
 SET [ConfigurationInterCaisse]. [InterCaisseID] = (SELECT [InterCaisse]. [ID] 
                                                    FROM [InterCaisse] 
                                                    WHERE [InterCaisse].Nom = [ConfigurationInterCaisse].NomConfiguration);
 GO
```

I asked if SQL Server Compact Edition doesn't support subquery?

If true, I need another solution for my problem...

Comment: yes it does support subquery. Maybe it would help if you tell us about the problem. Do you get an error message or what happens ?

Comment: I stand corrected: The limitation in SQL CE is that it does not support subqueries that return a scalar value. Subqueries that return a set are parsed fine.